Capture UIImage frame of AVPlayer streaming .m3u8 for given time is not giving image with proper aspect ratio
I am using the below code
property
let videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: [String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)])
    //and adding this videoOutput to playerItem

Then using below code to get image
guard let player, let pixelBuffer = videoOutput.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: player.currentTime(), itemTimeForDisplay: nil) else { return nil }
let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
let context = CIContext(options: nil)
guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return nil }
return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

I am not getting image in proper aspect ratio in which aspect ratio the video player was.
